# SQL Server non-clustered Index never shows up in execution plan

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan, query-performance

I have a database table called `tbl_event` with the non-clustered indexes `IDX_Event_Folder` and `IDX_Event_Time` defined as:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Event_Folder] 
ON [dbo].[tbl_event]([nobjectid] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Event_Time] 
ON [dbo].[tbl_event]([tetime] ASC)
```

I ran the following simple queries and got the execution plans displayed directly underneath:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_event 
WHERE tbl_event.nobjectid = 1410000
ORDER BY tetime
```

[image: Execution Plan for Query 1]

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_event 
WHERE tbl_event.nobjectid = 1410000
```

[image: Execution Plan for Query 2]

My question is, why is the index on **nobjectid** never utilized? I would expect there to be an index seek or scan when nobjectid is specified in the where clause of these select statements. Is my understanding of this analysis incorrect?

Comment: Can you please post the table defintion including (!) the primary key definition?

Comment: How many rows are in the table? How many of them have the value `1410000`?

Comment: 18325170 rows currently in the table, only about 30 of them have nobjectid=1410000

Comment: OK that definitely sounds extremely odd to me that the index would not be used. With a 1:610839 selectivity. Are you sure that it hasn't been disabled? You can see this in `sys.indexes`. Also do you have auto create statistics and auto update statistics turned on? Also what if you try and force the issue `SELECT * FROM tbl_event  WITH (INDEX = IDX_Event_Folder) WHERE tbl_event.nobjectid = 1410000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say in the comments that there are 18325170 rows currently in the table, only about 30 of them have nobjectid=1410000.

Even if your `IDX_Event_Folder` index was disabled I cannot believe that SQL Server would choose this plan for that amount of rows and the line thickness indicates it thinks it is dealing with maybe 1 row not 18325170!

[image: Plan]

So I'm pretty sure that you must have auto update statistics disabled? If so you will need to update the statistics manually (or preferably enable this option)

Comment: This was the issue. Now when I run the select query I am seeing an Index Scan on IDX_Event_Folder.

Comment: @mjh41 - Index seek hopefully (and some RID lookups)?

Comment: yes, you are right - an index seek (not scan) with a cost of 5% and an RID lookup with a cost of 95%

Answer (score 3):

> why is the index on nobjectid never
>   utilized? I would expect there to be
>   an index seek or scan when nobjectid
>   is specified in the where clause

A common misconception!

One point is: since you're using `SELECT *`, you want all data from the table. So in the end, SQL Server must go back to the actual data pages and fetch all the values.

When an index seek occurs and finds a hit, then in this case, SQL Server has to do a bookmark lookup - a rather expensive operation.

And since those operations are rather expensive, SQL Server will try to avoid them if it can - so in many cases, a table scan will be used instead, since in the end, that's faster than seeking the nc index and then doing a bookmark lookup.

Points to check:

- how **selective** is the `nobjectid` column? This one here sounds like a more or less unique ID - that would be good. If you happen to have an index on a column that would be not very selective, then often, the query optimizer will ignore it (since it would have to check too many rows already, so a table scan is quicker in the end)
- how many **rows** are there in the table?? For small tables (less than a few thousand rows), it's often much faster to do a table scan from the get go

Also, from your first execution plan with the "RID heap lookup", I would conclude you don't have a clustered index on the table - **add one right away**!! Not having a clustered key (thus having a **heap** instead of a clustered table) also slows down lots of operations and reduces the effectiveness of a non-clustered index.

Try to add your clustered index on a "NUSE" column:

- narrow
- unique
- stable
- ever increasing

`INT IDENTITY` is a perfect candidate - `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` or a very wide compound set of columns are the worst. Read all about choosing the **right** clustered index at [Kimberly Tripp's blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/Clustering-Key.aspx)

Comment: Plus: IS there a primary key?

Comment: there is no primary key on this table.. records in this table are associated with objects identified by nobjectid. For 1 object there can be n records in tbl_event.

Comment: @mjh41: *if it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table* - add a good primary key to that table, and make it a good clustering key, too!

Comment: The OP says there are 18325170 rows in the table and only 30 match the predicate...

Comment: @Martin: true - that definitely sounds quite selective and should have used the index; seems like your hunch was right (again!)

Answer (score 1):

There are several overlapping things going on

- Your `SELECT *` means "give me all columns". The optimiser decides it's more useful to scan the table instead.
- The only useful index is the tetime one for ordering. It does this, then drills into the table.
- You have no clustered index (the RID/heap lookup shows that)
- The lack of uniqueness on the nobjectid index won't help: it means an full index scan. o why use the index when combined with  `SELECT *`?

If you had this, then the index will be used (as a scan)

```
SELECT nobjectid
FROM tbl_event 
WHERE tbl_event.nobjectid = 1410000
```

Or this, the new index would most likely be used

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Co,bined] 
ON [dbo].[tbl_event]([nobjectid] ASC, tetime)

SELECT nobjectid, tetime
FROM tbl_event 
WHERE tbl_nobjectid = 1410000
ORDER BY tetime
```

I suggest you read these articles

- [SQL Server Index Basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/)
- [Using Covering Indexes to Improve Query Performance](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/)

The lack of clustered index should be covered by these articles too